# Select the littlest hovered element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I guess the question is in the title: I want to apply a style only to the littlest hovered element when the user clicks. How do do I choose this very element ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you say what this function is?  Preventing the hover from bubbling doesn't help here, because you likely already fired the `mouseenter` or `mouseover` on the parent on the mouse's way to the child, so even if you prevent the bubble, it already happened on the parent...if it's a class you can remove it from ancestors though, just depends what you're after.

Comment: Please be more detailed. I assume you mean "smallest"? But in what context - when are there multiple elements hovered? Can you make a real life example?

Comment: I'm sorry. 
I want to apply a style to a <div> inside one or more <div>  when the user click on this element.

Thank you for your remarks

Comment: clik or hover?... hmmmm more confused... :(

Comment: Damn, my question is going weird ! Hover

Comment: @Coronier - You want to apply the a class to the most child element, but not it's parents?, e.g. moving from parent to child removes it from parent?

Comment: Yes, only to the most child element - and actually in my project, to the elements who share the same class that my hovered element -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a style on the div and not have the parent affected, you can stop the bubble with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("myClass");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You can see a demo of this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/HsBDQ/)

For the `hover` case, you actually would want `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (which [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) binds to) in this case, like this:

```
$("div").mouseover(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass("myClass").parents().removeClass("myClass");
  e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("myClass");
});​
```

[You can see this in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/HsBDQ/1/)

Comment: I tried this:   


 $('div').hover(
        function(e){
            $('div').addClass('hovered')
             e.stopPropagation();
        },
        function(e){
            $('div').removeClass('hovered')
            e.stopPropagation();
        })


But it applies the style to all the DIV of the page :(

Comment: @Coronier - You're using `$("div")` inside the function, not `$(this)` like my example :)  Take a look here, I think this is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/HsBDQ/1/

Comment: I feel so stupid ...  It (of course) works now. 

Thank you Nick for your patience.